# How do I utilize git with multiple working directories?

Tags: git

I am attempting to use git however am having difficulty understanding how I can use it with multiple working directories for each project. The examples I have found online seem to suggest a single repository.

For example I have a directory for each project e.g. Project A, Project B, etc. These can be located in the same path or different paths e.g. local drive, network share.

I would imagine each of the projects has its own repositories. Does this mean that each project would require its own .git initialization directory or is the standard and recommendation to use a single git repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you would set each project up in it's own directory, with it's own repository in it's own `.git` directory.

Git is very light-weight. You just have the normal project directory, you cd to it, and you do `git init`, prepare a `.gitignore` file, do `git add .` and then do your first commit.

The `.git` directory contains zipped versions of all the files in the working directory (sort-of). But it won't really save any interesting amount of space to lump several projects together.

The only reason for putting all your projects in the same directory is if you indeed want them all to share version control history. If they are truly independent projects, it makes no sense to put them in the same repository.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that may be the case however wanted to understand the standard approach.

Comment: This needs to be stressed: Do not put multiple projects into the same git repository (unless you know what you are doing). Git loves the one project = one repo approach and you will get annoyed if you don’t follow it.

Comment: @Chronial - Thanks. Can you give an example of a use case that you would have multiple projects in a single repository?

Comment: I actually know of only one: Project dependencies that you manage with `git subtree`.

Comment: @Chronial or git submodules.